# jQuery AJAX call won't update database

Tags: php, jquery

I've been learning how to update databases using jQuery and AJAX so you don't need to refresh the page when you submit something, but I'm a little bit stuck.

This example is quite simple - you click the "accept" button, and in the database, the column "accepted" is updated to be '1' instead of '0'. The jQuery function appears to be working correctly, but the value isn't updating. I've tried switching from `data: 'id='+id` to the JSON `data: { id: data }` approach, as well as just using `.val()` instead of `.serializeArray()`, but nothing seems to work. Any advice?

**form.php**

```
<form id='acceptGoal' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='$gid'>
<input type='button' id='submit'>Accept?</button>
</form>
/* $gid is the unique identifier of each individual item to be accepted */
```

**script.js**

```
$('#submit').click( function() {
    var data = $("#id").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "accept.php",
        datatype: "json",
        data: { id: data }
        });
    });
```

**accept.php**

```
require 'core/initialize.php';
$query=$db->prepare("UPDATE goals SET accepted=:a WHERE id=:i");
$query->bindParam(":a", $a=1);
$query->bindParam(":i", $_POST['id']);
if ($query->execute()) {
    echo "Done";
    }
else {
    echo "Something went wrong.";
    }
```

Comment: Look in the [network tab of the error console](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820). Is the form being submitted and what data does it send? What is the server's response? If you add `print_r( $_POST )` to the PHP script what does it say?

Comment: The form is being submitted, but the data length is apparently 0. I'm getting nothing from print_r that I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first,you have syntax error at the end, an extra comma there:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "accept.php",
        datatype: "json",
        data: { id: data }, //<--------  Here is mistake 
        });
```

second, your hidden field does not have **id** attribute with the value **id**:

```
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='$gid'> // no id attribute in it while you accessing in jquery
```

while you are accessing it:

```
var data = $("#id").val(); // this will return nothing as element with this id not exists
```

change it to:

```
<input type='hidden' id='id' name='id' value='$gid'>
```

you have to do like this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "accept.php",
            datatype: "json",
            data: { id: data } 
            });
```

and you should add **success** and error **callback** to check it ajax call was successful or error occured:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "accept.php",
            datatype: "json",
            data: { id: data },
            success:function(response){
            alert(response);
            },
            error:function(response){
             alert("error");
            }  
            });
```

Comment: That was a typo of mine as I uploaded the question, the comma doesn't actually exist in the code.

Comment: check the update, you are also accessing a hidden field with id that does not exists

Comment: That has made the data come through, but the database still won't update?

Comment: well thats server side matter now you have check your php code